# ArcGIS Pro Summarize Within produces no output

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing

I tried to use the Summarize Within tool on some dummy data but got no output. In trying to understand what I was doing incorrectly I found this ESRI [tutorial](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/summarize-data-inside-of-polygons/) and tried that but with the same problem - it runs without any errors - indicates that the function has run but the output feature class is not created.  Could it be a licence issue - where the function runs but doesn't allow access to the output feature class?

[image]

Summarize Within Parameters and Messages below:

**Parameters:**
Input Polygons     Districts
Input Summary Features     Dams
Output Feature Class     C:\users\temp\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages\Gujarat_8c2719\p30\gujarat.gdb\Districts_Dams
Keep all input polygons     KEEP_ALL
Summary Fields     gross_storage_capacity_km3 Sum;reservoir_area Sum
Add shape summary  attributes     ADD_SHAPE_SUM
Shape Unit
Group Field
Add minority and majority attributes     NO_MIN_MAJ
Add group percentages     NO_PERCENT
Output Grouped Table

**Messages**

Start Time: Sunday 4 December 2022 13:17:52
Succeeded at Sunday 4 December 2022 13:17:52 (Elapsed Time: 0.21 seconds)

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the Messages *as text* in the body of the Question.

Comment: I think it is probably outputting but to the workspace GDB. Are you expecting that the feature will be the source GDB? If so then you need to path it to that GDB.